# Ошибка Socket'a (Python 3) TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, сокет

Не могу понять почему всегда появляется ошибка TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Вот скрин, вроде бы все верно: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого используйте ссылку «[edit]», расположенную под метками вопроса.

Answer (score -1):

Какая версия питона? Судя по докам sendto должно выглядеть так:

```
s.sendto('данные',(host,port))
```

Если третий питон то строку данных еще нужно конвертить в bytearray.

А еще в доках написано (The socket should not be connected to a remote socket, since the destination socket is specified by address.) что перед sendto ненужно изначально делать connect, sendto сам соединяет сокет.

Comment: Обновил, все как в доках было сделано. Вот скрин http://imgur.com/a/GApyK

Comment: Ну вот опять непонятки.Питон версию тяжело глянуть? Приводишь строку в int не понятно зачем.Первый параметр send и sendto имеет тип bytearray.Если 2 версии питон то надо просто строку передать, а если 3 питон то нужно преобразовать сначала string в bytearray.

Answer (score -1):

Дело в том, что обычную строку нельзя отправлять, только последовательность байтов.
Решение:

1. `bytes('данные','ascii')`
2. `'данные'.encode('ascii')`

Используй другие кодировки, если это необходимо